# What is difference between $d\vec{l}$ and $\vec{dl}$?

Tags: vectors, notation, differentiation, calculus

What is difference between $d\vec{l}$ and $\vec{dl}$? $d$ means differential as usual.

Comment: There is no difference.

Comment: Do provide us with a usage of both notations. Would help to clarify things in between.

Comment: By which I mean, somebody who was extremely particular about their notation might want to make them different. But there’s no universal distinction here, most people won’t care.

Comment: @knzhou Exactly, thats why if the OP *needs* a difference, we need a reference.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's [about notation](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1083/25301)

Comment: good versus bad typesetting?

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference.

In my view :

- $d\vec l$ means the differential of some vector $\vec l$ ; this could be the position vector of some particle for example. In this case, d$\vec l$ will be an infinitesimal variation of that pre-defined vector $\vec l$.
- $\overrightarrow{dl}$  would be some infinitesimal vector (like an infinitesimal displacement), without any reference to a predefined vector $\vec l$. However, note that if that is not an exact differential (that is, if $\vec l$ can not be defined), it should be noted $\overrightarrow {\delta l} $ instead, as with work $\delta W$ for example.

So I feel like the first notation insists somewhat more on the nature of that vector being a differential. In any case, both are correct.